# Catch the event when play button clicked

Tags: html, database, html5-video

I'm using html video tag to play videos in my website.i want to update the database when user click the play button in the video.how can i catch that event?
can someone please help me.Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `playing` event is fired when the video starts playing, for the first time, after being paused or when restarting.
Let's say the id of your video element is `videoclip`

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById('videoclip');
var videoController = videoElement.controller;
if (videoController) {
  videoController.addEventListener("playing", playHandler, false);
}
else {
  videoElement.addEventListener("playing", playHandler, false);
}

function playHandler(e) {
  // This handler will be called when the video starts playing, for the first time, after being paused or when restarting.
}
```

This [HTML5Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) gives a primer on the events of the video element.
This [w3 demo](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) demonstrates the action live. Click the play button on the video and see how the `playing` event counter increments every time.

Comment: Does this differentiate between then the video element is clicked and the actual play button on the controls?